# How update Laravel to 6?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-6

I am trying to upgrade laravel to version 6 to php 7.4. How can I change the composer (its content is below) so that it pulls the plugins of compatible versions necessary for the project?

Compatibility errors occur when changing only laravel version

how do I understand which versions of plugins to write in composer so that it builds projects correctly? I have a lot of problems with him when changing versions ...

```
    {
    "name": "Codecast's Single Page Application Starter Kit",
    "description": "This is the web service to support the kit.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "0.8.*",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "~1.0",
        "predis/predis": "~1.1",
        "league/fractal": "0.14.*",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~2.3",
        "scriptixru/sypexgeo": "0.2.*@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/Support/",
            "tests/TestCase.php",
            "tests/ApiTestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "test": "phpunit --colors=always",
        "check-style": "phpcs -p --standard=PSR2 --runtime-set ignore_errors_on_exit 1 --runtime-set ignore_warnings_on_exit 1 ./app ./config ./routes",
        "fix-style": "phpcbf -p --standard=PSR2 --runtime-set ignore_errors_on_exit 1 --runtime-set ignore_warnings_on_exit 1 ./app ./config ./routes"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to upgrade laravel step by step. From version 5.3 to 5.4. From 5.4 t 5.5 and so on. At last, upgrade from 5.8 to 6

Comment: Thank you. the only problem with determining the versions of the required plugins for each upgrade step. how to understand which version, for example, barryvdh / laravel-cors is needed when upgrading to laravel 5.4, and which when upgrading to 5.5 for example. can not understand

Comment: updated to php 7.4 and had a lot of problems with plugin versions

Comment: It might be easier to remove the other dependencies, update Laravel and then re-require them in to your project without a version so that composer can decide which version should be installed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?